# 2 Nivo Sliders on same page not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, nivo-slider

For some reason that I can not see, I have two nivo sliders on the same page that do not work. Help much appreciated. Below is the well known Nivo Slider code that I am adapting.

Header

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/default/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/light/light.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/dark/dark.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/bar/bar.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Nivo Slider 1

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
        <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
            <img src="images/toystory.jpg" data-thumb="images/toystory.jpg" alt="" />
           <img src="images/up.jpg" data-thumb="images/up.jpg" alt=""/>
            <img src="images/walle.jpg" data-thumb="images/walle.jpg" alt=""/>
            <img src="images/nemo.jpg" data-thumb="images/nemo.jpg" alt=""/>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Nivo Slider 2

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
<div id="slider2" class="nivoSlider2">
<em><img src="images/up2.jpg" data-thumb="images/toystory2.jpg" alt="" title="Hello, My name is Daisy and I am a mobile beauty specialist covering the Cambridge area." data-transition="fade" />
<img src="images/walle2.jpg" data-thumb="images/up2.jpg" alt="" title="My clients know that when they come to me, they will get the service and the look that they want. I really can help you be that face that gets noticed in the crowd." data-transition="fade" />
<img src="images/nemo2.jpg" data-thumb="images/walle2.jpg" alt="" title="However I am not just a specialist in applying make-up, I offer luxury manicures and pedicures, Sienna X spray tanning, massages and a lot mot" data-transition="fade" />
<img src="images/toystory2.png" data-thumb="images/nemo2.jpg" alt="" title="This is an example of a caption" data-transition="fade" />
        </em></div>
</div>

</div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({pauseTime:10000});
    $('#slider2').nivoSlider({pauseTime:5000});
    effect:'fade'
});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know what NIVO is but having 2 elements with the same ID, is wrong `id="wrapper"`.

Comment: Why do you have all of the images in the second slider wrapped in `em` tags? Also, your effect syntax is incorrect. Chances are that you're receiving a Javascript error. Check your console.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues here.

1. You have duplicate IDs. I doubt this is the problem but it's bad practice.
2. You have `<em>` tags around your images in the 2nd slider.
3. Finally, you have incorrectly specified your `effect` parameter - this is most likely the cause of the issue

   ```
   $(window).load(function() {
       $('#slider').nivoSlider({pauseTime:10000});
       $('#slider2').nivoSlider({
           pauseTime:5000,
           effect:'fade'
       });
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Please change `<div id="wrapper">` for one of the slider and then check.

**Note:** you shouldn't have same id's for both div's(not only divs) anytime.